# How to pause and then return setInterval

Tags: javascript

I'm fixing some errors in the chat that is in development here in the company. Currently what has happened is that the messages loaded in the chat window do not belong to the selected chat. Queries in DB and Java methods are correct.

Since a setInterval () is being used, I believe that when I select a different chat, if the setInterval method has already been triggered, messages are loaded incorrectly.

Is there a way to trigger the setInterval only after loading the messages and pausing it when clicking another chat?

Method I want to update:
PS: Without the setInterval, it does not show incoming messages. Just by clicking on chat again.

```
 function atualizarChat(idChat,nomeChat)
                    {
                        // Parametros
                            var dados = "Token=" + encodeURIComponent(token);
                            if(idMensagemUltima != 0){
                                dados += "&idChatMensagem="+encodeURIComponent(idMensagemUltima);
                            }                           
                            dados += "&idChat="+encodeURIComponent(idChat);

                            $.ajax({
                                type : "POST",
                                url : "/ListarMensagensServlet",
                                data : dados,
                                dataType : "json",
                                success : function(resultado) {

                                idChatEscolhido = idChat;

                                    // Troca nome do chat
                                    if(nomeChat != ''){
                                        $('#NomeUsuarioChat').text(nomeChat);
                                    }   

                                    var mensagemAntiga = idMensagemUltima;

                                    // Adiciona as mensagens na tabela
                                    for(mensagem of resultado){                 

                                        if(mensagem['bool'] == 1){
                                            mostrarSuaMensagem(mensagem['mensagem']);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            mostrarRespostaMensagem(mensagem['mensagem']);
                                        }
                                        // troca data da ultima mensagem
                                        idMensagemUltima = mensagem['idChatMensagem'];
                                    }

                                    if(idMensagemUltima > mensagemAntiga){
                                        // Joga chat para baixo
                                        $('#CaixaDeChat').stop().animate({
                                            scrollTop: $('#CaixaDeChat')[0].scrollHeight
                                        }, 800);
                                    }                           
                                }


                            });                         
                    }
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: you should post your problem in english, people here are from all over the world and you are limiting your help to only your specific community :) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please move your question to Portuguese StackOverflow (pt.stackoverflow.com).
About your solution,

I suggest create a small function to handle this behavior, you just need to create a `setInterval` and set their value into a variable.

```
var interval = null;

var intervalHandler = function(status, yourFunction, intervalTime) {
   if(status) {
     interval = setInterval(yourFunction, intervalTime);
   }
   else {
     clearInterval(interval);
   }
}
```

So, `status` is a `boolean` variable with value `true/false`. Value `false` will execute `clearInterval` condition and `true` will execute the `setInterval` condition.

Using:

```
intervalHandler(true, yourFunction, 1000);  // for set

intervalHandler(false);  // for clear
```

Comment: Thank you so much. With this solution the problem was solved.